# C#. Universal desition for storing different types

Tags: c#, json, generics, types

I'm looking for the best approach of working with different types identically.

I have a web service that goes to specific resource, makes some research and returns an object `WebResult`, that contains all information about completed operations.

And now I'd like to build a set of different metrics, that will describe all received results. These metrics should provide

- different types of data
- easy way to collect it
- possibility to deserialize it.

**Example 1**

First I've created separate classes for different metrics

```
public abstract class AbstractStatistic
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }

    public abstract void FillAllMetrics(WebResult result);
}

public class Resource1Statistic : AbstractStatistic
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string[] Table1_Header { get; set; }
    public int Table1_RowCount { get; set; }
    public string[] Table2_Header { get; set; }
    public int Table2_RowCount { get; set; }

    public override void FillAllMetrics(WebResult result)
    {
        this.Url = result.url;
        this.Title = result.data["title"];
        this.Table1_Header = result.data["table1.header"].ToObject<string[]>();
        //...
     }
}
```

It works, but I'd like to make it in more standard way. One of the reason is that in this approach I have to create separate web form for each metrics.

**Example 2**

Second working example is universal but redundant: create an abstraction of any datatype

```
public abstract class AbstractStatistic
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Exception { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Metric> Metrics { get ;set;}

    public abstract void FillAllMetrics(WebResult webResult);
}

public class Metric // Specific class for data
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public int? IntegerValue { get; set; }
    public string[] ArrayValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTimeValue { get; set; }
}

public class Resource1Statistic : AbstractStatistic
{
    public override void FillAllMetrics(WebResult result)
    {
        this.Metrics.Add("title", 
            new Metric() { StringValue = result.data["title"].ToString() });
        this.Metrics.Add("Table1 Header", 
            new Metric() { ArrayValue = result.data["table1.header"].ToObject<string[]>() });   
        //...
    }
```

It works, but I'm sure there is more elegant solution. I don't like to take all these null values in json.

**Examples 3**

Generic solution (regarding to Adwaenyth)

```
public abstract class AbstractStatistic
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Exception { get; set; }
    public List<AbstractMetric> Metrics { get ;set;}

    public abstract void FillAllMetrics(WebResult webResult);
}

public abstract class AbstractMetric{}

public class Metric<T> : AbstractMetric
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; private set; }

    public Metric()
    {
        this.Type = typeof(T).ToString();
    }
}

public class Resource1Statistic : AbstractStatistic
{
    public override void FillAllMetrics(WebResult result)
    {
        this.Metrics.Add(new Metric<string>() 
          { Name = "title", 
            Value = result.data["title"].ToString() });
        this.Metrics.Add(new Metric<string[]>() 
          { Name = "Table1 Header",  
            Value = result.data["table1.header"].ToObject<string[]>() });   
        //...
    }
```

This solution looks nice, but I have to write custom deserializer.

What do you think, is there some good pattern that fits to my task? Or what's the best approach?

Comment: The problem with deserializing a generic is, that in your `Metric<T>` the deserializer has to determine the type for `T` somehow. It needs to be either predefined or extrapolated by analyzing the data, but it would be something you have to implement yourself on deserialization. Then it it absolutely possible to have a `Dictionary<string, Match<T>>`.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I don't understand this thing:
If I have generic attribute like `Dictionary<string, Metric<T>>` in my class, that means that my class is generic on `BaseClass<T>`.

How can I create such object if I have a different types of data: 
`new BaseClass<object>()`? It seems to me, that this is a bad approach - use `object` as Generic value.
What do you think?

Comment: As said, you have to derive your specialized deserialization mechanic. `BaseClass<object>` will not work because - while you might be able to deserialize basically anything into `object` - you cannot cast it to `BaseClass<T>` by default. This has to be done by the deserializer which calls the appropriate `BaseClass<T>` constructor. It might be necessary to implement that via reflection... Also the Dictionary will rather have an abstact type `Dictionary<string, Metric>` with the generic metric `Metric<T>` being derived from an abstract `Metric` base class.

Comment: Thank you! That's really simple idea - to inherit Metric<T> from abstract Metric. I'll add your version as **Example 3**

Comment: Regarding your abstract class `Metric<T>` you do not need to set the type name each time you assign a value. The type is fixed to the instance while constructing the object. it will not change afterwards. E.g. you can't assign an `int` value to a `Metric<string>` as this causes a compile time error.